# How convert this consult in LinQ

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to convert in this query

```
from lckr in BD.Inventory_Lockers join emp in BD.Employees on lckr.EmployeeID equals emp.EmployeeID 
join jti in BD.JobTitles on emp.JobTitleID equals jti.JobTitleID 
join dpt in BD.JobTitles on jti.DepartmentID equals dpt.DepartmentID  
select new { DepartmentN =  dpt.Department.DepartmentName, asignationDate= lckr.asignation_date, lockers = lckr.LockersID.Count() } 
.ToList())
```

Comment: Convert to what?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to convert to T-SQL, it would be as follows

```
SELECT 
     dpt.DepartmentName AS DepartmentN
    ,lckr.asignation_date AS asignationDate
    ,COUNT(lckr.LockersID) AS lockers
FROM Inventory_Lockers lckr
JOIN Employees emp ON emp.EmployeeID = lckr.EmployeeID
JOIN JobTitles jti ON jti.JobTitleID = emp.JobTitleID
JOIN Department dpt ON jti.DepartmentID = dpt.DepartmentID 
GROUP BY 
     dpt.DepartmentName
    ,lckr.asignation_date
```